# PHP Echo Table Column Alignment

Tags: php, css

I have this code that works fine in other pages that I made but doesn't work properly on my summary page.

```
<?php
        //AAFES-date1
        $sqlAAFES1 = "SELECT * FROM aafes WHERE dueDate ='$date1'";
        $qAAFES1 = $pdo->prepare($sqlAAFES1);
        $qAAFES1->execute(array($date1));
        $dataAAFES1 = $qAAFES1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($dataAAFES1){
            echo '<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">';                                                   
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($pdo->query($sqlAAFES1) as $rowAAFES1){
                echo '<td width="60%">'.$rowAAFES1['facilityName'].'</td>';                 
                echo '<td style="text-align:right" width="40%">'.$rowAAFES1['totalQty'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            echo '</table>';                                    
        };      
        };
?>
```

[image]

as you can see the 2nd row doesn't align with the first row.

[image]

while on the other page, I used the same `foreach` code, but alignment is perfect. So I wanna ask what seems to be the problem with this one.

Comment: Why are you running the query twice? there's absolutely NO point in preparing/executing the query, fetching a single row, then directly re-executing the exact same query. If you want to see if there's any rows available, then check `$qAAfes1->rowcount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't close `foreach` loop after table. Put `<tr></tr>` inside `foreach` loop.

```
if ($dataAAFES1){
    echo '<table class="table table-condensed table-hover">';        
            foreach ($pdo->query($sqlAAFES1) as $rowAAFES1){
                echo '<tr>';
                  echo '<td width="60%">'.$rowAAFES1['facilityName'].'</td>';                 
                  echo '<td style="text-align:right" width="40%">'.$rowAAFES1['totalQty'].'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            };
    echo '</table>';   
};
```

Comment: Don't just repost a blob of code without explain WHAT you changed.

Comment: Yes. you did. you just put in a chunk of code with no explanation of what you'd changed. But since you've now added an explation, i'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Thanks For Being So Kind. @MarcB

Comment: Worked like a charm! Perfect. Thank you @NanaPartykar

Comment: Glad To Help :) *Keep Coding..!!*